# jQuery change attribute in HTML stocked in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to dynamically generate inputs, but I need to give them a different input name.
First, I put the content of my html template in the variable:

```
var template = $("#question_template").html();
```

Then I add an index so I can distinguish each added block of inputs:

```
var question_html = "<div id='question_" + indice_question + "'>" + template + "</div>";
```

But now I'm trying to change the name of the inputs like this:

```
$(question_html).find('input').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name','question[question'+indice_question+']'+$(this).attr('name'));
});
```

The problem is my `question_html` is not updated in the process, and when I do

```
console.log($(question_html).html());
```

The input names are the same that in my "template".

Here is the full code:

EDIT: snippet is not working but fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7085/

```js
indice_question = 0;

$('#add_question').on('click',function(){

    var template = $("#question_template").html();
    var question_html = "<div id='question_" + indice_question + "'>" + template + "</div>";

    $(question_html).find('input').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('name','question[question'+indice_question+']'+$(this).attr('name'));
        console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    });
 console.log($(question_html).html());

 $('#question_list').append(question_html);
 indice_question++;

});
```

```html
<div id="question_list">
</div>

<button type="button" id="add_question">Add question</button>

<div id="question_template" style="display:none">
    <label for="question_content">Question content</label>
    <input type="text" name="[question_content]"/><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="[id_question]" value=""/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `$(question_html)` will be a different jQuery object.

Instead of creating the HTML String, you should create a jQuery Object to manipulate it. Because when later you were trying to access `$(question_html)` it was just another jQuery object and not the previous one.

```
var question_html= $("<div id='question_"+indice_question+"'>" + template + "</div>");

question_html.find('input').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('name', 'question[question' + indice_question +']' + $(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Now when you will do console log, the names will be changed

```
console.log(question_html.html());
```

Comment: Hello @void , I followed your solution in my scenario: `var transfer_template = $('#transferTemplate').html(); $('input[type=text], select').each(function() { transfer_template.find(o => o.id === this.name).val( $( this).val() ); });`  but it didn't filled the input boxes...maybe something changed with newer jquery versions today?..

Comment: Solved my scenario... I used to create the template inside `<script type="text/x-custom-template" id="transferTemplate"></script>` and it couldn't be threatened as I wanted so I changed with `<template id="transferTemplate"></template>` then using DOM selectors like `var transfer_template = document.querySelector('#transferTemplate'); var clone = document.importNode(transfer_template.content, true);` I could threat the template's clone as I want! Hope it'd be useful for someone